# editMessageText a simple example js

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot

I really need a complete simple example(code) for bot.editMessageText/ReplyMarkup usage.
I use node.js, no framework, with standard telegram-bot-api module for Telegram
Shortly, somthing like this:

```
 let mes_id = 0;
 bot.onText(/\/start/, (msg)=>{
     bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'Some text')
     mes_id = msg.message_id
 })
 bot.onText('edit',(msg)=>{
     bot.editMessageText(msg.chat.id, mes_id, 'edited text'); //?!?! 
 })
```

I want previously sent message by bot to be edited, and could not find a full and understandable example on the internet.

Comment: You need to add more context. Where does this bot run for example? Do you use a framework or library and which version of it.

Comment: did you check this: [telegram bot REST API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#updating-messages) ?

Comment: telegram-bot-api node.js modul for TELEGRAM-BOT-API

Comment: and i have checked all of existing manuals, tutorials and articles ...

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can save the message you want to edit, like:

```
 let savedMsg = null;
 bot.onText(/\/start/, (msg)=>{
     bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'Some text').then((sendedMsg) => {
          savedMsg = sendedMsg;
     })
 })
 bot.onText('edit',(msg)=>{
     bot.editMessageText(msg.chat.id, savedMsg.message_id, 'edited text'); //?!?! 
 })
```